# Staticly assert that enum is a certain underlying type

Tags: c, enums, c99, static-assert, misra

MISRA 10.1 forbids performing arithmetic on an object of an enumerated type.

> An operand of essentially enum type should not be used in an arithmetic operation because
>   an enum object uses an implementation-defined integer type. An operation involving an
>   enum object may therefore yield a result with an unexpected type. Note that an enumeration
>   constant from an anonymous enum has essentially signed type.

They also stipulate that the `++` and `--` unary operators are treated as binary addition and subtraction for the purpose of this rule.

If I use integers in the loop control structure I'll still need to cast them back to enum later, which will violate Rule 10.5

> The value of an expression should not be cast to an inappropriate
>   essential type

Is there a way I can use static assertions to guarantee some assumptions about the underlying enum type? This code may be reused in the future on another architecture. I'd like to deviate from 10.5 in this case with confidence that the code will throw a compile time error if some assumption about what the underlying enumerate type is violated.

Contrived example:

```
enum {thing1, thing2, ... , thing_max } thing_index_t
...
for(int thing_index = 0; thing_index < (int) thing_max; ++thing_index)
{
    init_something((thing_index_t) thing_index);
    //             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    // cannot cast a signed value to an enum type
    // [MISRA 2012 Rule 10.5, advisory]
}
```

This should always be a safe cast if I statically assert that `sizeof(thing_index_t == int);` and that `thing1 == 0u` right?

Int will always be large enough to hold my whole range of values without promotion FWIW.

Comment: It is a constraint (=> a guaranteed compile time error if violated) that enumerator constants must be integer constants expressions representable as an int. The underlying type of the resultant enum type then must be capable of holding all the enumerator constant values. Consequently, casting any enum type to int needs to be safe (as long as the enum type doesn't store un-enumerable values) regardless of what the underlying type is.

Comment: That was my thinking too even when typing up my little example. My particular implementation might use unsigned char in this case, or signed char, but if I stick with int it doesn't matter.

Comment: Please note that _underlying type_ was a MISRA-C:2004 formal term. It has been retired, MISRA-C:2012 only speaks of _essential type_. Their definitions are different: the former is "the type the operand would have if not for implicit promotions", the latter is determined by a listing of groups of operands: signed, unsigned, enum etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rule 10.5 is overall sound, but controlled conversions from `enum` to signed/unsigned aren't dangerous. MISRAs concern is that you might have an enum like `enum {thing1=123, thing2=456, ...`. But if you know that the enumerator constants are from 0 to max, it is then mostly safe to go to/from integers.

You don't need a formal deviation for advisory rules. I would rather leave a comment such as

```
/*  Violates MISRA 10.5 but iterating from thing1 to thing_num is safe. 
    Integer type is used since arithmetic on enums is forbidden by 10.1. */
```

(Or use whatever process you have in place for dealing with advisory rules.)

---

As for static asserts, `sizeof(thing_index_t == int)` proves nothing, since the allowed enumeration constant values is what matters. And `thing1 == 0u` is guaranteed by the C standard so you don't need to assert that.

A static assert to ensure enum integrity should rather look like

```
#define THING_VALUES   \
  thing1,              \
  thing2,              \
  thing_num            \

typedef enum { thing1=123, thing2=456, thing_num } thing_index_t;
const size_t expected_size = sizeof((thing_index_t[]){ THING_VALUES }) / sizeof(thing_index_t);

_Static_assert( thing_num+1 == expected_size );
```

where the compound literal `(thing_index_t[]){ THING_VALUES })` gets a size corresponding to the number of enumeration constants in the list. `expected_size` is the number of items. This asserts that no special initializers such as `thing1=123` are present.

The only loop hole is something exotic like `thing1=123, thing2=1`, which this won't catch. To protect against that, you would need to go even further with macros, implementing the whole thing with X macros etc.

Comment: IHMO when you decide to bookkeep *all* enum names in a second list, it would be wiser to also generate the enum from this list.

Comment: I think this would catch your "something exotic" after all: `(thing_index_t[]){ thing1=123 }` would be a syntax error.

Comment: @Jander Ah that's right, the initializers would have to be kept separate. So X macros or something similar after all. I'll fix this example.

Comment: Wait, that syntax error is a good thing! :)  If the OP wants assurance that every number from 0 to thing_num is a valid enum constant, then throwing a compile error if the `thing1=123` syntax is used is a great idea.